# Binary Logistic Regression Interpretation: Significant with no change in model

Tags: regression, logistic, spss

I recently ran a logistic regression. I am seeing significant p-values, but there is no change between block 0 and block 1. Is this representative of a type I error?

[image: Output Part 1]

[image: Output Part 2]

[image: Output Part 3]

Comment: It could be helpful to post your regression output here too.

Comment: no clear to me what it means by "no change between block 0 and block 1"

Comment: Yes, i concur with hxd. I have no idea how to interpret this output.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has nothing to do with type I error. What is happening is that your cutoff value for predicting the result is set at 0.5 and the addition of the independent variable, while signficant, doesn't move any cases to category 2.  Try changing your cut value.